# How can should one separate and purify benzophenone from salicylic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, purification, recrystallization, separation-techniques

I am working with two solids and I know that they are  benzophenone (s)(ketone) and salicylic acid (s) (carboxylic acid). I am curious to know what is/are the best method of extraction and purification?

In other words, would extraction be the only method that these two can be separated because one is neutral and the other is an acid?

Also, what kind of qualitative test/s can you use for salicylic acid? I mean I understand that the acid/base test is most commonly used but can you use it again to test for -COOH functional group?

Apologizes for the questions but not being able to physically see this makes this 10X hard basing this off of hypotheticals.

Comment: Are you familiar with solvent-solvent extraction?

Comment: Google the water solubulities of the two compounds

Comment: The partition coefficient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_coefficient) is used to describe the relative solubility of a compound in two immiscible solvents (e.g., organic:aqueous). This is the principle upon which the sovent-solvent extraction is based. This is where you would use a sep funnel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separatory_funnel).

Comment: An additional thought... You might also consider taking advantage of the fact that salicylic acid is an acid and would react with sodium bicarbonate. Looking up partition coefficients (logP) in PubChem gives logP = -1.43 in octanol:water for sodium salicylate and a computed logP = 3.4 for benzophenone.